# VBA - Shapes - .name - Runtime error '7': Out of Memory

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I have looked everywhere for over a few day period and nobody appears to have my problem. I am trying to make an embedded chart using information from a different worksheet and manipulating it (resize etc.)

Whenever I try to rename the chart from .name I get the mentioned run time error. 
To try to work around this error, I made .name as variable (LineSubject) and then tried to use that in the .Shapes(LineSubject) column but received an error saying it is unable to find the name of the shape. 
I have also found people have used .Parent.Name.. I am able to alter the name however this doesn't allow me to enter it in the .Shapes(NAME) space.

```
Set wLineGraphs = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Graphs")
wLineGraphs.Activate

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
Set LineChart = ActiveChart
    With LineChart
        .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
        .SetSourceData Source:=wGraphd.Range("A96:K99")
        .ApplyLayout (3)
        .ChartTitle.Text = HistRange
        .Name = GraphNumber <-- Error Here
        '.Parent.Name = GraphNumber
   'Parent.Name spits out "Chart 2"
        'LineSubject = .Name
   '.Name spits out "Graph Chart 2"
        '.Shapes("Chart 2").Top = wLineGraphs.Cells(360, 2).Top
        '.Shapes(LineSubject).Left = wLineGraphs.Cells(360, 2).Left
    End With
```

The end result I am looking for, is to be able to use the name of the chart in the .Shapes(INSERTNAME) so I am able to manipulate the chart freely.

Thank you for the help :)
p.s I am using Excel 2016, I have also tried this on Excel 2010 and same error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `.Name` property on the `Shape` object instead of the `Chart`:

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(332, xlLineMarkers)
    .Name = "name"
    With .Chart
        .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
        .ApplyLayout 3
        .SetSourceData Source:=ActiveSheet.Range("A96:K99")
        .ChartTitle.text = "title"
    End With

End With
```

Comment: If it's working maybe you should flag the answer as accepted?